# Sandbox mode for Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, virtualization

Does Ubuntu have something similar to Windows 10 Sandbox mode via ramdisk?

At the moment, the closest thing I have to this is VirtualBox, which seems overkill if I just want to quickly test an app in a safe/secure manner.

Comment: Would [firejail](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/firejail.1.html) meet your needs?

Comment: @DKBose, thank you for the suggestion, will give this a try now.